# Fontawesome giving 401 unauthorized error during build process

Tags: npm, font-awesome, yarnpkg, react-font-awesome

I've been using fontawesome with no issues for months. Today, I started seeing this error whenever I tried to push my app to production.

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://npm.fontawesome.com/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/-/6.1.1/fontawesome-pro-6.1.1.tgz: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"".
```

I've tried running `yarn install`, removing `node_modules`, removing `yarn.lock`, etc. and I still get 401 unauthorized. I even uninstalled and reinstalled all fontawesome packages.

I'm using Yarn, not NPM, so not sure if that has something to do with it. I do have a `.npmrc` file set up and that looks like:

```
// .npmrc

@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken="my-token"
```

I also have a `.yarnrc.yml` file

```yaml
// .yarnrc.yml

npmScopes:
  fortawesome:
    npmRegistryServer: "https://npm.fontawesome.com/"
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmAuthToken: "my-token"
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "br-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "jest",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 --quiet",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "storybook:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/.cache/storybook",
    "json-server": "json-server -p 5000 --host 0.0.0.0 --watch db.json",
    "compile": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@joeattardi/emoji-button": "^4.6.0",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.4.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.15.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.4.0",
    "@typeform/embed": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/auth0-js": "^9.14.2",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-modal": "^3.12.0",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.9.3",
    "auth0-js": "^9.19.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "firebase": "^8.2.4",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.20",
    "next": "10.0.5",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^6.0.0",
    "qs": "^6.9.6",
    "rc-slider": "^9.7.1",
    "rc-switch": "^3.2.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.4.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-easy-crop": "^3.3.2",
    "react-functional-select": "^2.9.5",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hotjar": "^5.0.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.12.1",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-query": "^3.5.16",
    "react-typeform-embed": "^0.2.1",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "recoil": "^0.1.2",
    "sharp": "^0.30.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "styled-jsx-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^10.0.5",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.18",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.18",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.18",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.20",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^3.1.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "husky": "^5.1.3",
    "import-sort-style-module": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "lint-staged": ">=10",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "prettier-plugin-import-sort": "^0.0.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "importSort": {
    ".js, .jsx, .ts, .tsx": {
      "style": "module",
      "parser": "typescript"
    }
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "pre-push": "tsc --noEmit"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,scss,md,json}": "prettier --write"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question. The issue ended up being with my dockerfile. According to the fontawesome installation instructions you need to run these two commands in your terminal:

```
npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/
npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" "your token here"
```

But, if you use docker you'll need to add these two commands to your dockerfile:

```
RUN npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/
RUN npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" "your token here"
```

That way, the config gets set when you deploy.

So my whole dockerfile now looks like...

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/
RUN npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" "my token"
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the a `.npmrc` file [as documented](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/packages) on Font Awesome's site
you can add this line to bring that file into the Docker environment.

This works with yarn as well.

```
COPY .npmrc ./
```